# Android use .so file got error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I use bsdiff.so file for my project from [here](https://github.com/shoyu666/bsdiffAndroidDemoWithSo).

here my project structure.

[image]

i added  `jniLibs.srcDirs` to my build.gradle file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testbsdiff"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            //jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

i have two class from that library for use this c file.

BsPatch:

```
import java.io.File;

/**
 * patch入口
 * Created by shoyu666 on 16/7/12.
 */
public class BsPatch {
    public static final String TAG = "BsPatch";

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("bsdiff");
    }

    /**
     * patch操作
     *
     * @param old    老的apk路径
     * @param patch  补丁路径
     * @param newapk 新的apk路径
     */
    public static native void bspatch(String old, String patch, String newapk);

    /**
     * 测试下库是否正常
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static native String test();

    /**
     * 启动一部patch
     *
     * @param files
     */
    public static void patchSync(File... files) {
        BsPatchAsyncTask task = new BsPatchAsyncTask();
        task.execute(files);
    }
}
```

BsPatchAsyncTask:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.File;


/**
 * 异步patch
 * Created by shoyu666 on 16/7/11.
 */
public class BsPatchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, File> {
    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(File... files) {
        if (checkParams(files)) {
            File old = files[0];
            File patcher = files[1];
            File newFile = files[2];
            try {
                BsPatch.bspatch(old.getAbsolutePath(), patcher.getAbsolutePath(), newFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (newFile.exists()) {
                return newFile;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    private boolean checkParams(File... files) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (files != null && files.length == 3) {
            File old = files[0];
            File patcher = files[1];
            File newFile = files[2];
            if (old != null && patcher != null && old.canRead() && patcher.canRead()) {
                if (newFile.exists()) {
                    newFile.delete();
                }
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and when use this class and library in mainactivity i got this error:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: ir.javadroid.testbsdiff.BsPatch.test:()Ljava/lang/String;
                                                                         at ir.javadroid.testbsdiff.BsPatch.test(Native Method)
                                                                         at ir.javadroid.testbsdiff.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

main activity:

```
 BsPatch.test();
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
        final File oldApk = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "appV1.apk");
        final File destApk = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "newApp.apk");
        final File patch = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "path.apk");
        BsPatch.patchSync(oldApk, patch, destApk);
```

Comment: I did not find the relevant cpp file, so I can only guess. The error is about not finding 'test' method with the proper signature - the code expects to find ir.javadroid.testbsdiff.BsPatch.test. Is it possible the cpp implementation does not have the right signature, with the proper package name as JNI requires?

Comment: thanks for comment. the so file's copied from that library. i don't familiar with ndk in android. from your comment and after some search i figure out that so file have diffrent package name. so i need use c file and compile that to so then use the file for new package. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Basically, the function name must contain the package hierarchy of the Java caller (you can avoid that by using env->RegisterNatives, if you want). You can also look here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Comment: @yakobom thanks for answer.